# getTitle() is not able to fetch the title of my page inside junit @test anotation

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, junit4

hello i m new to selenium webdriver.i want to verify the page title in my junit test.but using         getTitle() i m able to find title in @before but not able to get title inside @Test.can any one solve this issue.
here is my code:
        package junitTestCase;

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import junit.framework.TestCase;

    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Rule;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


   public class TestCase1 extends TestCase
    {

 public static  WebDriver driver;

@Rule
    public ErrorCollector er=new ErrorCollector();

@BeforeClass
  public static void testDraiverConection()
  {

    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Before
   public void testLogintoApp()
{
    driver.get("http://127.0.0.1/login.do");
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys("manager");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}
@Test
   public void testTc1()
{

    System.out.println("title is:" + driver.getTitle());
    String expectedResult="actiTIME - Open Tasks";
    String actualResult=driver.getTitle();
    try
    {
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult,actualResult);   
    System.out.println("PASS  "+expectedResult+"="+actualResult);
    }
    catch (Exception t)
    {
        er.addError(t);
        System.out.println(t);
    }

}
@Test
    public void testTc2()
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Projects & Customers']")).click();
    try{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        er.addError(e);
    }
    String expectedResult="actiTIME - Active Projects & Customers";
    String actualResult=driver.getTitle();
    try
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult,actualResult);
        System.out.println("PASS  "+expectedResult+"="+actualResult);
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        er.addError(t);
        //System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
@After
 public void testLogout()
{

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@alt='Logout']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Is the getTitle string blank or you are getting any error?
What is the code, u are using inside @Before for getting the Title?

Comment: Have you tried using other waits than that implicit one? So you make sure the next page is fully loaded?

Comment: @nrbafna:-for testTc1()  the failure trace is:org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[actiTIME - Open Tasks]> but was:<[]>

Comment: @aimbire:i tried Thread.sleep(8000);BUT it is not working

Comment: @HemChe:i am not getting error.my junit test case is getting failed because it is not matching the expected result with actual result as in the code.but i m useing getTitle() to fetch  the title of the page.but i am not getting means getTitle() is working fine for before annotation.but it is not working for Test annotation  public void testTc1() 
{ } method.

Comment: You are mixing JUnit3-style and JUnit4-style syntax. Remove the "extends TestCase"

Comment: @NamshubWriter:yes it is working if i remove extends TestCase.but i want to run my script through my driver file.so if i will remove extends TestCase ,then it will through error.and JUnit3-style and JUnit4-style syntax mixing means?i am not getting it.can u plz expalain it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove "extends TestCase"

The classes under the junit.framework package predate JUnit 4. Unless you are in a project where you are required to use JUnit3-style tests, you should stick to the JUnit classes under org.junit. Using both junit.framework and org.junit classes in the same test file can lead to bizarre behavior.